# Member activation query

Tags: users, registration, activation

I have a site where am registering users via the front-end.
I want to use email address as username and also want people to define their password on registration.

I have set the following in `general.php`:

```
'useEmailAsUsername' => true,
'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,
'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'register/success',
'verificationCodeDuration' => 'P1W'
```

However, when a user registers via the front-end - or I resend the activation link via the Control Panel - they are directed to a page/URL eg `actions/users/verifyemail?code=XXXX&id=XXXX` and get the following error message:

```
Oops!

Invalid verification code. Please login or reset your password.
```

Can't figure out why the verification code is not working.
Any suggestions?

Cole

Comment: Further to this - if I copy the activation link from the back-end I get a different URL: `actions/users/setpassword?code=XXX&id=XXX` rather than `actions/users/verifyemail?code=XXXX&id=XXXX`

Answer (score 1):

Solved - bizarre one this.
Was using a third-party email service via SMTP and it was manipulating the URL somehow. Switching to use a direct SMTP connection with a specific email account has resolved.

Go figure!